# Assistance with VBScript to monitor folder for files then rename and move them

Tags: vbscript, monitoring, rename, move

So first off, my apologies as I am a total noob when it comes to VBScript. I have been googling and trying examples of code I have found for the last several days and I just can't seem to be able to put the pieces together.

The intent of the code I need to write is to monitor a folder for files. When a file is written to a specific folder, I need to be able to get the filename and shorten it to less than 80 characters, then move it to a different folder leaving the original folder empty. If the File happens to already have less than 80 characters in the filename then I would prefer to leave the name alone and just move it to the different folder. The file name that are dropped in the monitored folder have fairly random names.

I have found quite a few examples of how to rename a file using VBScript, but these all predicate you already have the file name.

I have also found a couple of examples of how to monitor a folder using WMI events, but I haven't figured out how to tie these together.

Any help with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the names of all files in a directory.

```
    Dim fso, folder, files, sFolder
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFolder = "C:\DOCUME~1\Philip\LOCALS~1\Temp"
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
    Set files = folder.Files
    For each k In files
        WScript.Echo k
    Next
```

Comment: That's a beginning. That script is one time use though, correct? That's fine, I can simply use Task Scheduler to execute it every couple of minutes or so. But, how would I go about staring with that and then using it to rename and move the files? From what I read I would replace "WScript.Echo k" with something else? Like the rename command with a LEN argument to trim the length of the filename?

Comment: Marichyasana thank you for your post. I was able to use what you posted and hack together something that worked for me. The part I was missing was how to get the names in the folder, which you provided. Thanks again. :)